# mysql procedure error when creating

Tags: mysql

I cannot create procedure. MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'set @pid=people_ids; SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id) INTO @ids FROM tbl_people W' at line 3

```
delimiter //
create procedure my_coordinate(in people_ids varchar,out oids varchar(200))
  BEGIN
   SET @ids = null;
   set @pid=people_ids;
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id)    INTO @ids
   FROM tbl_people 
   WHERE upper_bos_id = @pid ;

set oids= @ids;
IF @ids  then
  CALL my_coordinate(@ids);
END IF;
end//
```

Comment: in varchar field needs a length. Also do you really want the procedure to call itself?

Answer (score 0):

Remove 1 line to not explicitly set `@ids` to null first (not tested, so attempt 2, or 3):

```
delimiter //
create procedure my_coordinate(in people_ids varchar,out oids varchar(200))
  BEGIN
   set @pid=people_ids;
   SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( id)    INTO @ids
   FROM tbl_people 
   WHERE upper_bos_id = @pid ;

set oids= @ids;
IF @ids  then
  CALL my_coordinate(@ids);
END IF;
end//
```